# IBMMQDotnetClient connecting with TLS 1.2 + kdb certificate

Tags: c#, .net-core, ibm-mq

Im trying to connect to IBM MQ using the .net library "IBMMQDotnetClient" version 9.2.3, this connection has to be with TLS 1.2.

```
        properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
        properties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, _hostname);
        properties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, port);
        properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channel);
        properties.Add(MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, @"C:\Root\ssl\keystore");
        properties.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY, "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256");
        properties.Add(MQC.CERT_LABEL_PROPERTY, certLabel);
```

when I call the :

```
_mqQueueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManager, properties);
```

I get the following MQException: Reason 2195 - Message "MQRC_UNEXPECTED_ERROR"

Does anyone know how to connect to the IBM MQ from a c# .netcore project using a .kdb/.sth certificate?

On the MQTRACEPATH log I see this:

```
000001CA 13:08:12.582896   29080.1    -----------}  MQTCPConnection.ConnectUsingLocalAddr(ParsedLocalAddr,IPAddress,int) rc=OK
000001CB 13:08:12.582914   29080.1     IP:*****
000001CC 13:08:12.583357   29080.1     Constructing IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.MQEncryptedSocket#0083A9E6 MQMBID sn=p923-L210708 su=_rwPC4d_rEeuJxYd83sYP-w pn=basedotnet/nmqi/NmqiObject.cs
000001CD 13:08:12.583376   29080.1     Constructing IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.MQEncryptedSocket#0083A9E6 MQMBID sn=p923-L210708 su=_rwPC4d_rEeuJxYd83sYP-w pn=basedotnet/nmqi/MQEncryptedSocket_s.cs
000001CE 13:08:12.583712   29080.1    -----------{  MQEncryptedSocket.RetrieveAndValidateSSLParams(MQConnectOptions)
000001CF 13:08:12.583850   29080.1     IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.MQEncryptedSocket#0083A9E6 throwing MQException: cc=2 rc=2381
000001D0 13:08:12.584052   29080.1     New MQException CompCode: 2 Reason: 2381
000001D1 13:08:12.586100   29080.1    -----------}! MQEncryptedSocket.RetrieveAndValidateSSLParams(MQConnectOptions) rc=(Unknown(2381))
000001D2 13:08:12.586901   29080.1     CompCode: 2, Reason: 2381
000001D3 13:08:12.586982   29080.1     New MQException CompCode: 2 Reason: 2538
000001D4 13:08:12.588392   29080.1    -----------{  ManagedCommonServices.GetMessage(string objectId,uint returncode,uint control,out string basicmessage,out string extendedmessage,out string replymessage,MQLONG basicLength,MQLONG extendedLength,MQLONG replyLength)
000001D5 13:08:12.588428   29080.1     Returncode: 0x20009202 Control: 0x00000006
000001D6 13:08:12.590143   29080.1    -----------}! ManagedCommonServices.GetMessage(string objectId,uint returncode,uint control,out string basicmessage,out string extendedmessage,out string replymessage,MQLONG basicLength,MQLONG extendedLength,MQLONG replyLength) rc=(Unknown(536895768))
000001D7 13:08:12.591130   29080.1    -----------{  ManagedCommonServices.DisplayMessage(string,string,uint,uint)
000001D8 13:08:12.634418   29080.1    ------------{  ManagedCommonServices.GetMessage(string objectId,uint returncode,uint control,out string basicmessage,out string extendedmessage,out string replymessage,MQLONG basicLength,MQLONG extendedLength,MQLONG replyLength)
000001D9 13:08:12.634472   29080.1     Returncode: 0x20009202 Control: 0x00000013
000001DA 13:08:12.634686   29080.1    ------------}! ManagedCommonServices.GetMessage(string objectId,uint returncode,uint control,out string basicmessage,out string extendedmessage,out string replymessage,MQLONG basicLength,MQLONG extendedLength,MQLONG replyLength) rc=(Unknown(536895768))
000001DB 13:08:12.634805   29080.1    -----------}! ManagedCommonServices.DisplayMessage(string,string,uint,uint) rc=(Unknown(536895768))
000001DC 13:08:12.634880   29080.1    ----------}  MQTCPConnection.ConnectSocket(string,string,MQLONG) rc=OK
000001DD 13:08:12.634996   29080.1     CompCode: 2, Reason: 2538
000001DE 13:08:12.635362   29080.1     New MQException CompCode: 2 Reason: 2538
000001DF 13:08:12.635379   29080.1     New NmqiException CompCode: 2 Reason: 2538
000001E0 13:08:12.635498   29080.1    ----------{  MQFAPConnection.CleanUp(Boolean,NmqiException) inputs  [False] [CompCode: 2, Reason: 2538]
000001E1 13:08:12.635514   29080.1    ----------}  MQFAPConnection.CleanUp(Boolean,NmqiException) rc=OK
000001E2 13:08:12.635594   29080.1    ---------}  MQFAPConnection.Connect(MQConnectionSecurityParameters) rc=OK
000001E3 13:08:12.635614   29080.1     CompCode: 2, Reason: 2538
000001E4 13:08:12.635738   29080.1    --------}  MQConnectionSpecification.CreateAndConnectConnection(MQConnectionSecurityParameters,MQFAP,String,MQConnectOptions,int) rc=OK
000001E5 13:08:12.635761   29080.1    -------}  MQConnectionSpecification.GetSessionFromNewConnection(MQConnectionSecurityParameters,MQFAP,String,MQConnectOptions,int) rc=OK
000001E6 13:08:12.635768   29080.1     Exit AssingSession from new connection:
000001E7 13:08:12.635775   29080.1    ------}  MQConnectionSpecification.GetSession(MQConnectionSecurityParameters,MQFAP,String,MQConnectOptions,int) rc=OK
000001E8 13:08:12.635782   29080.1    -----}  MQFAPConnectionPool.GetSession(MQConnectOptions,MQConnectionSecurityParameters,MQChannelDefinition,String,int,String,String,int,int) rc=OK
000001E9 13:08:12.635791   29080.1     CompCode: 2, Reason: 2538
000001EA 13:08:12.635847   29080.1     New MQException CompCode: 2 Reason: 2538
000001EB 13:08:12.635857   29080.1     New NmqiException CompCode: 2 Reason: 2538
000001EC 13:08:12.635906   29080.1     CompCode: 2, Reason: 2538
000001ED 13:08:12.635973   29080.1    ----}  MQFAP.NmqiConnect(String,NmqiConnectOptions,MQConnectOptions,Hconn,Phconn,out int,out int,ManagedHconn) rc=OK
000001EE 13:08:12.636003   29080.1     CompCode: 2, Reason: 2538
000001EF 13:08:12.636016   29080.1    ---}  MQFAP.MQCONNX(String,MQConnectOptions,Phconn,out int,out int) rc=OK
000001F0 13:08:12.636026   29080.1     IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager#03551B1B throwing MQException: cc=2 rc=2538
000001F1 13:08:12.636033   29080.1     New MQException CompCode: 2 Reason: 2538
000001F2 13:08:12.654150   29080.1    --}! MQQueueManager.Connect() rc=(Unknown(2538))
```

Answer (score 3):

Managed mode which is the only mode supported in Core uses the Windows user or system keystore.  You need to specify `*USER` or `*SYSTEM` as your `MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY`.  You will need to import your cert to the corresponding Windows key store.

Note that in managed mode the cipher you specify is only used to determine the TLS version to use, the actual negotiated cipher may not be what you specify.  In your example it will negotiate to a TLS1.2 cipher. If the SVRCONN SSLCIPH does not match what is negotiated the connection will fail. If the queue manager is also at 9.2 you can specify `ANY_TLS12` or `ANY_TLS12_OR_HIGHER` in the SVRCONN SSLCIPH to allow it to accept any available TLS1.2 cipher negotiated.